# Add preprocess to content within body field

Tags: nodes, theming

I need to be able to wrap an anchor tag with rel="shadowbox" and href with the path to the image on all img tags that are inserted into the body field of a node. I think I can somehow do this with preprocess?

I realise that I can have a field of images and do it that way, though the client wants the images within the body text itself.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple different ways one could go about this; I think the most elegant solution could be a text filter.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_filter_info().
 */
function MODULE_filter_info() {
  $filters = array();

  $filters['shadowbox'] = array(
    'title' => t('Image Shadowbox'),
    'description' => t('Wraps images in anchor tags.'),
    'process callback' => 'MODULE_shadowbox_cb',
  );

  return $filters;
}
```

Then, the callback:

```php
/**
 * Image shadowbox callback.
 *
 * @param string $text
 *   The text to be parsed.
 * @param object $filter
 *   The filter, which includes context about which format is being used.
 *
 * @return string
 *   The replaced content.
 */
function MODULE_shadowbox_cb($text, $filter) {
  $ret_val = $text;
  // Logic goes here.
  return $ret_val;
}
```

You'll need to enable the filter:

- /admin/config/content/formats/full_html
- /admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

Now, for the content of the callback; you could use a regular expression. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456866/4619035 is an example for exactly this use case. The downside of regular expressions with HTML is that they're fragile, especially with potentially malformed code. A workaround would be to sequence the filter after anything that cleans up HTML.

Alternatively, use DOM to manipulate the content - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316527/php-dom-wrap-image-in-link-and-add-span-before-image-tag describes this approach well.